# Changing the font color of display header in CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, haml

I'm working to export csv data from rails. I'm following the tutorial here: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-csv-export/

In controller:

```
def export
  @team_status_updates = @team.team_status_updates.team_updates
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
      headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"Team-report-#{DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%L")}.csv\""
      headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
    end
  end
end
```

In view export.csv.haml

```
- headers = ['DATE', 'TYPE', 'TEAM MEMBER', 'STATUS', 'COMMITMENT', 'QUANTITY', 'HOUR-DAY-WEEK?', 'EFFORT']
= CSV.generate_line headers, :col_sep => "\\"
- @team_status_updates.each do |team_updates|
  - if team_updates[1].length > 0
    - team_updates[1].group_by { |d| d.created_at }.each do |status_updates|
    - member_wise = status_updates[1].group_by { |d| d.member }
    - member_wise.each_with_index do |status_update, index|
      - standup_questions = status_update[1].sort!
        - standup_questions.each do |update|
          = CSV.generate_line([update.created_at.strftime("%a %b %d %Y"), update.kind, update.member.full_name_titlecase, update.body, commitments_url(update.commitment), update.commitment.time_to_complete_time,  update.commitment.time_to_complete_units, update.commitment.time_to_complete], :col_sep => "\\")
```

The issue here is that, I need to display header "red" font-color.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: CSV is a plain text format, it doesn’t have things like fonts or colours. (Also Haml isn’t really a good choice for generating CSV).

Comment: Is any gem available to add that feature in CSV. Thanks - @Matt

Comment: It’s nothing to do with how it’s generated. CSV is basically plain text, you _can’t_ specify the colour like this. Perhaps you need to look at creating a spreadsheet file file xlsx.

Comment: That should be “like xslx” in my previous comment, not “file xlsx”.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [exporting-csv-and-excel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) video from rails cast. like @matt say CSV are plan text XLS can contain formatting.

key notes: 
in the file **config/initializers/mime_types.rb** make sure to add `Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls`

and create a `export.xls.haml` here you can add a table in haml like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Release Date</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Price</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= product.id %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= product.name %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= product.released_on %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= product.price %></Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Now in your  **products_controller.rb**

```
def export
  @team_status_updates = @team.team_status_updates.team_updates
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
      headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"Team-report-#{DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%L")}.csv\""
      headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
    end
    format.xls 
  end
end
```

I hope that this is able to help.